# What do you call a merging of two franchises?

Tags: word-request

I thought the word was "crossover", but I tried to google for "lego and lord of the rings crossover", but couldn't find anything, so I am wondering if there's a more suitable word for it.

Let's take this sentence as an example:

> Lego Lord of the Rings, the video game is a Lego and Lord of the Rings
>   ___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker, I can't think of any word I would use in your example other than "crossover". While I can't find any dictionaries online that include this specific definition ("crossover" has many definitions), it is discussed on Wikipedia at "[Crossover (fiction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(fiction))". First sentence: "A crossover is the placement of two or more otherwise discrete fictional characters, settings, or universes into the context of a single story." That's an exact match to your example. If you're searching for a specific crossover and not finding it, could you explain exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: There's an [example for a video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts) in Wikipedia: *Kingdom Hearts is a **crossover** of various Disney properties based in a fictional universe.* I don't think Lego Lord of the Rings is really a crossover in this sense though because Lego video games have always come in different flavors - Lego Batman, Lego Star Wars, etc. Wikipedia calls them "Lego-themed" games.

Comment: @ColleenV: True, but I would still consider it a crossover, albeit in a slightly different sense. The Lego games aren't just themed like Lego- they use the rules of the Lego universe. For example, an object can be shattered into a pile of pieces, and then those pieces can be used to build something completely different.